# Laravel uploading to Heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, encryption, upload

Hello guys so I uploaded my app to Heroku. I want to mention that when I run php artisan:serve it all works fine without any problem but when I upload it to the heroku server I have a problem with the following error

The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.

Now I had the same error localy but I fixed it. now I can't seem to find how to fix it when I the app is uploaded. Any help would be appriciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have seen this response which was very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60923108/laravel-with-heroku-how-do-i-fix-app-key-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a key in your .env

```
php artisan key:generate
```

And make sure `.env` exists

Comment: Yep thank you apperantly the .env file was not uploaded for some reason

Answer (score 0):

As @EddyTheDove mentioned,

> php artisan key:generate

This makes sure that the APP_KEY variable is set in the .env file. When you open the .env file, you should see the same key that was generated after you executed the command.

#### And make sure .env exists

This is located in your project folder.

ALSO:

#### Remember to use the ENTIRE key.

The "base64:" part of the generated key is also important, because it encodes the random string and provides an encryption key of the required length.