# Laravel with heroku -> how do I fix app_key problem?

Tags: laravel, heroku, aes

I have been working on a Laravel application and started to push to Heroku for production testing. I am following the Heroku documentation for a laravel application and am getting the following error:
**"The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths."**

I have been searching for similiar problems and solutions and all of which I ahve tried; they say to run:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

even generate a new key sometimes. None of this works though. I do have a .env as well as the .env.exmaple.

this is in the app.php:

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'hApwwlSuskUu66CxJTWzCKS17fkExEkodmJiVXbMf0Q='),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

and equally the .env has this line after the cache:

```
APP_KEY=base64:hApwwlSuskUu66CxJTWzCKS17fkExEkodmJiVXbMf0Q=
```

What else do I do? I followed the Heroku documentation to the letter and beyond.

Reference:
Laravel 6.18.3
php: 7.3.2
composer: 1.9.3
heroku 7.22.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your app.php

```sh
'key' => env('APP_KEY', $_ENV['APP_KEY'])
```

or you can also try this

app.php

```sh
'key' => env('APP_KEY')
```

then run

```sh
heroku config:set APP_KEY=$(php artisan --no-ansi key:generate --show)
```

Comment: many thanks! this was bugging me a lot. such simple solutions and yet it worked flawlessly. I did the top one, with the default value drawing from the env variable, and of course ran that heroku config command. All is working now both locally and on my psuedo production system. cheers.

Comment: I am glad I can help. Cheers